# Dtype changed when loading file in Python with np.load

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

When I use python 3 to `numpy.load` a file, the `dtype` will be changed then caused me an error in later code.

Originally it's `[('data_date', [('year', '<i4'), ('month', '<i4'), ('day', '<i4')]), ('', '|V4')]`
After loading, it becomes `[('data_date', [('year', '<i4'), ('month', '<i4'), ('day', '<i4')]), ('f1', '|V4')]`

--notice that the last dtype in the list was an empty field, but somehow, when python3 loads the file and makes it `('', '|V4')` to `('f1', '|V4')`, and makes my code not recognize the shape and data type of file.

I had it "fixed" by hard-coded to save with `astype(by redefining the dtype with ('', '|V4'))`.

Does anyone know why Python 3 would change the dtype by opening it? Is there any other way to avoid this instead of saving the file with `astype()`.

Thank you very much.

When I do

````
loaded = np.load('the_file.npz')
database = loaded['database']
database.dtype```

#The output will be [('data_date', [('year', '<i4'), ('month', '<i4'), ('day', '<i4')]), ('f1', '|V4')]

#When I use the file format viewer application(make no change to the file), the dtype is just 
#[('data_date', [('year', '<i4'), ('month', '<i4'), ('day', '<i4')]), ('', '|V4')]
````

Comment: What is the legitimate need for an empty field name? Just asking.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? If I try : `x = np.array([('Rex', 9), ('Fido', 3)], dtype=[('', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4')]) ; x.dtype`, the first (unnamed) field is already renamed `'f0'`. So the issue seems present even before np.save. Maybe your issue is more with unnamed fields than np.load?

Comment: No need for the empty field, I can just delete it. The issue is, when I generate the file, it also generate the empty field. and when I load with python it automatically fill a dtype name for that empty field.